# the slight doubt expressed in this is, of course, crucial

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following context is about surveillance. Does the bold sentence want to say that people somehow know that they may be monitored, but they are not sure, because they may not be really monitored, and this suspicion and uncertainty (of whether being monitored or not) is something important?

From [*Art in the City* by Nicolas Whybrow](https://books.google.com/books?id=36j3AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=and%20the%20slight%20doubt%20expressed%20in%20this%20is,%20of%20course,%20crucial.&source=bl&ots=X2LNOcOr1W&sig=T6Dkc9aJ6ZjyXdGuwziSZN5456c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_06ec8ZvNAhUC7B4KHR9hB7UQ6AEIJjAD#v=onepage&q=and%20the%20slight%20doubt%20expressed%20in%20this%20is%2C%20of%20course%2C%20crucial.&f=false):
[image: screenshot of original source]

Comment: More context would be helpful.

Comment: The first problem is that the first part says that people assume they are being monitored but it doesn't say that people express any doubt at all about that assumption.  Assuming that the assumption is always accompanied by a small doubt about the validity of the assumption, the second problem is we don't know what this doubt is crucial to.

Comment: Sorry for the screen shot rather than text source, Google Books doesn't play nicely on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

The author appears to be distinguishing an assumption that most people make from something that people are told outright.

If people in a supposedly free society were told that they were constantly being monitored, they would probably protest this, fearing a *1984*-like dystopia.

But since they aren't told about it, but just suspect it, the slight doubt allows them to live with it without rebellion. If they thought about it rationally, they would realize it's the same thing, but emotionally they're different.